# Windows 7 Pro RDP to Windows 10 Pro, Get NLA error when attempting reconnect

Tags: windows-7, rdp, windows-10

Working on a poor connection, I get occasional packet loss that causes the RDP session to drop. When it drops, it displays the message "Connection lost, attempting to reconnect 1 of 20..." When it reconnects, RDP displays an error "The identity of the remote computer cannot be verified. Do you want to connect anyway? [Yes] [No]" If I click yes I get an error that my computer doesn't support NLA and then RDP closes the connection, and if I click no, RDP closes the connection.

Either way, I can immediately reconnect without error.

I have no idea what's causing this. Any suggestions?

Comment: “Working on a poor connection.” Have you considered the problem is your “poor” connection? Sometimes the answers are right in front of you.

Comment: Absolutely :-) however, with other machines (all Windows 7 I think) it will drop out and then reconnect as needed. I don't have much control over internet connection due to location :-( This is the only one that gives the identity question and then the NLA error during reconnect